# If $(I-T)^{-1}$ exists, can it always be written in a series representation?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras

If $X$ is a Banach space, and $T:X \to X$ is a bounded linear operator with norm < $1$, then $I-T$ has a bounded inverse defined by $(I-T)^{-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty T^n$.

Thinking in terms of a converse, if $T$ is any bounded linear operator defined on $X$, then does the existence of a bounded inverse $S=(I-T)^{-1}$ imply that $S$ can be represented as $S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty T^n$?

Comment: Just added some tags.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, not even in the finite-dimensional case. If $T$ is a linear map
from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself with all eigenvalues $>1$ in absolute
value, then $I-T$ is invertible, but $\sum T^n$ certainly does not
converge.

Comment: not even in dimension 1: 1-2 is invertible but $\sum_n 2^n$ does not converge

Answer (score 5):

Well there are slightly weaker condition that improves the result you cite.

Suppose $T$ is a bounded operator with spectral radius $r(T)< 1$
Then by the spectral radius formula we have 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|T^n\|^{1/n} =\inf_n\|T^n\|^{1/n}=r(T)< 1$$ 
which ensure the convergence of 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\|T^n\|$$
which in turn, by the triangle inequality, bounds 
$$\left\|\sum_{n=0}^\infty T^n\right\|$$ 
Now, it is a standard exercise to show that  
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty T^n=(I-T)^{-1}$$
If there is any doubt at all do not hesitate to ask..

**Edit:** By the Banach algebra inequality we have
$\|T^n\|\le\|T\|^n$, which means that $$r(T)=\inf_k\|T^k\|^{1/k}\le\|T^n\|^{1/n}\le\|T\|$$
 Hence $\|T\|<1$ implies not only $r(T)<1$, but also $r(T)\le\|T\|<1$. 

Also, this is not the case in the example of Robin above, because we also have $r(T)=\sup{|\lambda|:\lambda\in\sigma(T)}$ where $\sigma(T)$ is the spectrum of $T$ (the set of all $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\lambda I-T$ is not invertible) and the eigenvaules of $T$ is certainly in the spectrum. (Note that $r(T)$ is the radius of the smallest closed disc that contain $\sigma(T)$ - hence the name *spectral radius*).

Comment: Where is the text???

Comment: An extreme example is a nilpotent operator (i.e. $T^n=0$ for some $n$).

Comment: @AD: Fixed. I don't know why but it seems you have to type `&lt;` for `<`.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty cool. Can we get directly from the spectral radius formula that $r(T) < 1$ implies $||T|| < 1$?

Comment: @user1736: No, but conversely because $\|T^n\|\le\|T\|^n<1$ if $\|T\|<1$ -- we also have $r(T)=\lim_n\|T^n\|^{1/n}=\inf_n\|T^n\|^{1/n}$, waybe I should add that?.

Comment: @user1736: I just added this (and a bit more - I couldn't stop myself ;) ) into the answer.

Comment: Hm, isn't it always true that $\|T\| \geq r(T)$? I thought that if a number is in your spectrum, then the norm of your operator must always be greater than or equal to that number. I don't see why we need the Banach algebra inequality for that, but perhaps I'm missing something again..

Comment: The Banach algebra inequality is indeed useful here as seen above, but you are free to use a different argument for this.

Comment: BTW - I do not claim that this is *my* spectrum. This set called the spectrum is used in linear algebra, Fourier analysis, operator theory and functional analysis etc. I suggest that you look it up in Wikipedia.